# MS Visual C++ Runtime Library error on launch - any debugging tricks?

Tags: c++, msvcrt

When launching my app, I'm getting the below error dialog.  I understand this indicates a problem loading the runtime library.  The problem is, I'm not seeing any way to get more specific info.  Which library?  What was the exact problem it had when loading? etc..  System event viewer doesn't have any entries for it.  Are there any tricks to finding out exactly which library it was trying to load when it hit the error and what the specific problem was?

---

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Runtime Error!

Program: exe path

R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.*
```

My current approach for dealing with runtime lib dependencies is to scan the install directory, extracting out the embedded manifests for the .dll and .exe files and then generating .config and .2.config files to re-direct to the minor versions of the runtime lib I'm shipping with.  In the past this has always gotten things working.  Not so in this case.

This might be complicated somewhat by the fact that the calling code is native C++ but some of the DLLs use .NET.  I'm calling a C++ API, but under the hood it ends up utilizing some DLLs which themselves use .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SysInternals Process Monitor to monitor file system access.  Filter on process name and operation (CreateFile) to see what DLLs the process can't locate.

Comment: This was what finally helped me figure out the problem.  Turns out, there was a stray vc80 runtime library in the install directory in addition to having the sub-directories for the runtime libs (CRT, MFC, ...).  Getting rid of this fixed it.  It was incorrectly trying to load the one in the top dir which was not the correct version.  I found this using Process Monitor by seeing the last DLL it tried to load before the dialog popped up.

Answer (score 1):

It could indicate a wrong version of msvcr*.dll.

You could try Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out where it's being linked.

Comment: Is that tool manifest-aware?  I recall using dependency walker ages ago but it didn't seem to be aware of the manifest version stuff.  I'll take a look though.

Comment: Looks like the familiar depends I used to use in the past; sure, it tells you which DLLs something depends on, but in this case I think its perhaps a minor version conflict which requires the embedded manifest info to agree.  I don't think that tool is fine grained enough to see the minor version dependency information expressed in the embedded manifest files.  Not to mention, the problem here is I have a ton of DLLs, I have no idea which one is causing the problem.  I'd like to figure out where the problem is actually happening.

Comment: Well, dependency walker didn't do it.  It only tells you which DLLs, by filename, are in the import list for the module.  It doesn't understand the finer grained dependency information in the embedded manifests and doesn't, of course, know about libraries loaded at runtime (non import).  So while probably a useful tool for some things, it doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a debug version of the code you're trying to attach to. On the Debug menu, select Attach to Process. Use processID -

Also check this -http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235434
Resolution 1

You should be able to attach to the process using Task Manager:
Enable just-in-time debugging (JIT):
In Visual C++, on the Tools menu, click Options.
On the Debug tab, make sure that Just-in-time debugging is selected.
Run Task Manager and select the process to attach to. Right-click and select Debug.

Resolution 2

Run Task Manager and get the process ID for the process you want to debug.
At a command prompt enter the following:msdev -p 
This will start Visual C++ and will attach to the process specified.

Comment: Running from the debugger (VS2010) from source in a debug build doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: Both Resolution 1 and Resolution 2 and the link you provided are simply explaining how to attach to a process for debugging.  Not sure how that applies here.  My issue is not how to attach with the debugger, I can run it from the debugger.  The problem doesn't happen in a debug build btw.  I'm trying to get info on which library is having the problem.